# does anonymous category works in xcode5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have gone through [this](http://ijoshsmith.com/2010/11/09/anonymous-categories-to-the-rescue/)
for getting the idea of anonymous category.

But I found that I was not getting any warning when I have not declared the method while working with xcode 5.

Does anonymous category concept still work in xcode 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per this post [Objective-C class extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675201/objective-c-class-extension)

**Methods in class extensions**

From Xcode 4.4 (I believe), the compiler is clever enough to determine which methods are meant to be private within that implementation, removing the need to declare them elsewhere.

**difference between category and class extension**

the main difference between categories and extensions is that the extension expects you to implement the methods inside your main implementation, whereas with a category, it can be in another implementation. It also seems that people are using extensions mainly for private methods.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you see warnings depends on your compiler settings. And yes, they do still work in Xcode 5, they are a first-class feature of the Objective-C language.

Please note that the more common name for anonymous categories is a **class extension**.

Answer (score 0):

"Anonymous category" is called class extention. In modern Objective-C you do not need forward declaration of methods so declaring them in class extentions is not necessary.