# Why Xcode generates "unnecessary" code when create class?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I want to create an CocoaTouch class with Xcode,and it generates an **.h** and **.m** file,what's confused me is why **.m** file have such code:

```
#import "MealTableViewController.h"
//**************below looks unnecessary
@interface MealTableViewController ()

@end
//**************above looks unnecessary
@implementation MealTableViewController

@end
```

In my opinion,it looks like unnecessary because I have declared  this class implements `MealTableViewController.h`,and even I delete it,the result will be same as before.**So why this code will be generated automatically?What's the purpose of creating it?** Anyone knows please teach me,thanks!

Comment: This is for declaring private properties.

Comment: Read These 2 [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) __AND__ [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675201/objective-c-class-extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675201/objective-c-class-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ancient times, the Objective-C compiler needed to know the method names and signatures by the time the method was actually used. So if your class defined a method `- (void)foo:(NSString *)bar;` then the compiler must know about this before you could actually call `[self foo:@"bing"];`. You can't always "sort" your methods in such a way that methods are always defined before use (for example, if you have method `alpha` and method `beta` but both call each other). If you don't want to expose your internal methods in your `.h` file, you had to declare them in a class extension or category.

Nowadays, the Objective-C compiler is smart enough so it doesn't need this workaround any more. But if you want to declare *properties* that shouldn't be exposed in the `.h` file, you still need to do so in a class extension. That's why the default empty templates still adds an extension.

Answer (score 0):

`@interface` inside your `.m` file means you can declare here some private properties/methods